# How to Clear/Reset Local Test Instance

Tags: cleos, wallet

How to completely erase all the data from local EOS instance?

After shutting down nodeos and deleting all the files from both `~/Library/Application Support/eosio/nodeos/data` and `$HOME/eosio-wallet`, it's still possible to query wallet data.

`cleos wallet list`

shows:

`Wallets:
[
  "default"
]`

Related [issue on Github](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/2451).

Comment: to be sure that you're looking at the correct `eos-wallet` directory, try: `cleos wallet open -n boguswalletname`. The error message should show a path where it looked for the wallet file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To reset your chain data** on a local testnet you should:

- Stop your node
- Delete the **blocks** and **shared_mem** folders which you can find under:

  - Linux: `~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/data`
  - Mac OS: `~/Library/Application Support/eosio/nodeos/data`

**Deleting the wallets and imported keys** information is a separate and independent step (you don't need to reset your chain, you can just delete the wallet data and you can delete individual wallet files too).

One way to confirm you're looking at the correct wallets directory is to do:

`cleos wallet open -n boguswalletname`

This should result in something like: 

   `Error 3140002: Nonexistent wallet
   Are you sure you typed the wallet name correctly?
   Error Details:
   Unable to open file: /Users/yourusername/eosio-wallet/./boguswalletname.wallet`

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this problem as well and solved it by reopening the local blockchain as follows (`--hard-replay` is the key to avoid err when restarting):

```
pkill keosd
pkill nodeos 
keosd &
nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin -d /path/to/eos/contracts/eosio/data --config-dir /path/to/eos/contracts/eosio/config --access-control-allow-origin=* --hard-replay --contracts-console --http-validate-host=false —filter-on=‘*’ >> nodeos.log 2>&1 & 
rm -rf ~/eosio-wallet/default.wallet
```

After this, all wallet and account data will be deleted :D
Hope it helps:)